# devtools::install_github() fails on map drive or VM-based OS

Tags: r, github, installation, devtools

I am trying to install [this](https://github.com/Espanta/lubripack) package from github using `install_github("espanta/lubripack")`. When I run from a stand-alone machine (not a VM), it works fine and package gets installed easily. However, when I run the command on a OS that runs as a VM, it fails to install by throwing below error

```
Downloading GitHub repo espanta/lubripack@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/espanta/lubripack/zipball/master
Installing lubripack
"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.3/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore CMD INSTALL  \
  "C:/Users/Espanta/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpsRvcqY/devtools19007474782/Espanta-lubripack-b1dd9ee"  \
  --library="\\psf/Home/Documents/R/win-library/3.2" --install-tests 

* installing *source* package 'lubripack' ...
** R
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
*** arch - i386
Warning in library(pkg_name, lib.loc = lib, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE) :
  there is no package called 'lubripack'
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
*** arch - x64
Warning in library(pkg_name, lib.loc = lib, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE) :
  there is no package called 'lubripack'
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed for 'i386', 'x64'
* removing '\\psf/Home/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/lubripack'
Error: Command failed (1)
```

I run `Parallel Desktop` on my MAC to host Windows 7 OS. So the windows is installed on a network-like partition `(i.e., \\psf)`. But it fails installation.

Similar discussion was made [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14755033/r-custom-package-install-from-file-error) in another stackexchage thread, but in a slightly different context. Although in the 4th line of the above output the windows-like address is also provided `"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.3/bin/x64/R"`, it seems something still goes wrong. I think I should be able to explicitly give the address to install_github() function so it can identify the location. Any help is appreciated especially from Hadley Wickham who is the creator and owner of the Devtools package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just faced the same problem with Windows running in Parallels. Fixed it with the help of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698269/how-do-you-change-library-location-in-r).

I changed the default install library path from previously `"\\Mac/Home/Documents/R/win-library/3.2"` to `"Z:/Documents/R/win-library/3.2"` using

```
.libPaths("Z:/Documents/R/win-library/3.2")
```

Afterwards, `devtools::install_github` works. You may want to change `"Z:/"` to your specific connection letter.